# cygwin gdb Program received signal ?, Unknown signal

Tags: gdb, cygwin

my.cpp:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  printf("hello main");
  return 0;
}
```

build with gcc and then
i use gdb to run the program, error occurred.
gdb: unknown target exception 0x406d1388 at 0x75fca6f2

```
Program received signal ?, Unknown signal.
0x75fca6f2 in RaiseException ()
   from /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/KERNELBASE.dll
```

gcc info:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: i686-pc-cygwin
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.4.0 (GCC)
```

gdb info:

```
GNU gdb (GDB) (Cygwin 7.10.1-1) 7.10.1
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i686-pc-cygwin".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I changed my cygwin to 64 version, the problem is suprisely solved.
I think this may be another a bug which differ from the "well-known" GDB bug.

Answer (score 2):

It is a known bug for this version of GDB. [This](https://www.mail-archive.com/cygwin@cygwin.com/msg149735.html) link may help you.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but this can't solve my problem.i have tried this already.